# Django query for 3 tables

Tags: django, django-models

I have the following model structure Country, City(fk=country) and School(fk=city). Now I want to get list of countries with city, if city has a school. In my template, I want to do

```
for country in countrylist
    for city in getcitieswithschool
```

Can I get resultset with one query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get cities with

```
City.objects.filter(school__isnull=False).distinct().select_related('country')
```

Then [{% regroup %}](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#regroup) them by `country` and it will be clean and efficient.

Comment: Thanks so much!! just awesome! Never knew about regroup

Answer (score 1):

You can get them using this query

```
from django.db.models import Count

countrylist = Country.objects.all()\
    .annotate(cities_cnt=Count('city'), schools_cnt=Count('city__school'))\
    .filter(cities_cnt__gt=0, schools_cnt__gt=0)
```